# bad access exc_i386_gpflt on CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, ssl, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to establish TLS connection with my server, but it goes wrong on

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, str, 5555, &readStream, &writeStream);
```

with bad access exc_i386_gpflt. How can I fix it?

Full code

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream = NULL;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream = NULL;
CFStringRef str = (CFStringRef)"127.0.0.1";
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, str, 5555, &readStream, &writeStream);
if (readStream && writeStream) {
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);

    NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];

    NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream open];
}

if (readStream)
    CFRelease(readStream);

if (writeStream)
    CFRelease(writeStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)HOST, PORT, &readStream, &writeStream);
```

Comment: I need to connect to 127.0.0.1 on 5555 port, what I should write instead of (__bridge CFStringRef)HOST?

Comment: I try this 
`CFStringRef str = (CFStringRef)"127.0.0.1";
    CFHostRef host = CFHostCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, str);`, but now in host same error.

Comment: `const NSInteger PORT = 5555;
const NSString * HOST = @"127.0.0.1";
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)HOST, PORT, &readStream, &writeStream);`